# How to create an arbitrary state in QISKit for a local_qasm_simulator?

Tags: programming, qiskit

I would like to play with a quantum circuit `local_qasm_simulator` in QISKit, but I do not want to implement a separate quantum circuit that would prepare an initial state.

The way I do it now is by falling back to NumPy. Specifically, first, I extract matrix `u` from a quantum program `qp`:

```
cname = 'circuit name'
results = qp.execute(cname, backend='local_unitary_simulator', shots=1)
data = results.get_data(cname)
u = data['unitary']
```

Then, I explicitly create the state I need (e.g., $|\psi\rangle = \frac{1}{2}(|00\rangle + |01\rangle + |10\rangle - |11\rangle)$):

```
num_qubits = 2
psi = np.ones(2**num_qubits) / 2.0
psi[3] = -psi[3]
```

Finally, I apply `u` to `psi` with NumPy:

```
u @ psi
```

The advantage of this approach is that I can explicitly obtain the state $U |\psi\rangle$. However, I cannot use `local_qasm_simulator` and the `measure()` function.

So, how could I prepare an arbitrary state, and supply it to a circuit, and run a `local_qasm_simulator`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think you can use the `initialize` function as detailed at the section "Arbitrary Initialization" at [this tutorial](https://github.com/Qiskit/qiskit-tutorials/blob/master/tutorials/circuits/3_summary_of_quantum_operations.ipynb).

As an example, this tutorial explicitly shows how to initialize the three qubit state

$$ \frac{i}{\sqrt{16}} | 000 \rangle + \frac{1}{\sqrt{8}} | 001 \rangle +  \frac{1+i}{\sqrt{16}} | 010 \rangle + \frac{1+2i}{\sqrt{8}} | 101 \rangle + \frac{1}{\sqrt{16}} | 110 \rangle .$$

Which is done using the following lines of QISKit code.

```
import math
desired_vector = [
    1 / math.sqrt(16) * complex(0, 1),
    1 / math.sqrt(8) * complex(1, 0),
    1 / math.sqrt(16) * complex(1, 1),
    0,
    0,
    1 / math.sqrt(8) * complex(1, 2),
    1 / math.sqrt(16) * complex(1, 0),
    0]
initialize_circuit_3q = Q_program.create_circuit('initialize_circuit_3q', [qr], [cr])
initialize_circuit_3q.initialize("init", desired_vector, [qr[0],qr[1],qr[2]])
```

Comment: What if I don't want to initialize with any hard-coded vector but something more general? Something like `random_state` from this link?
https://qiskit.org/documentation/_modules/qiskit/quantum_info/random/utils.html

Comment: The link is broken...

Comment: Could anyone please provide some explanations regarding Qiskit `initialize`? The [new file](https://github.com/diego-plan9/qiskit-tutorial/blob/feature/doc-tweaks-stable/1_introduction/quantum_gates_and_linear_algebra.ipynb) does not seem to contain this info :(

Comment: Please refer to this link on some details of the initialization. Basically, it only guarantees the transformation from all-zero state: https://github.com/Qiskit/qiskit-tutorials/blob/master/tutorials/circuits/3_summary_of_quantum_operations.ipynb