# How to initialize classical register in Qiskit?

Tags: qiskit, cq-states

I'm working on a [Hybrid classical-quantum linear solver](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1903.10949.pdf). For this, they make a loop on a quantum circuit (ie. below), and each time they change the value of the classical register and apply a X gate on the quantum register conditioned on the state of the classical register. [image: quantum circuit]

Therefore, I ask myself, is there a way to initialize the classical register ?

Comment: You cant make classical bits as a controller and make qubits as a target. But you can use if conditional statement to apply x gate on the qubits.

Answer (score 2):

Classical registers are typically used for capturing measurement results, and may also be used for conditionally applying quantum operation. See:
https://github.com/Qiskit/openqasm/blob/master/spec/qasm2.rst

Given the problem you described, one approach would be to have a classical program that iteratively: 
1) defines and executes a quantum circuit on a quantum processor or simulator
2) reads the results from the classical registers for guidance in defining the circuit for the next iteration

Answer (score 0):

You might find this section of the documentation helpful, it goes over initializing and using registers.

https://qiskit.org/documentation/terra/quantum_circuits.html

Comment: I already read it, but they don't talk about classical register initialization.

Comment: What about this post: https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/1413/how-to-create-an-arbitrary-state-in-qiskit-for-a-local-qasm-simulator

Comment: In this post, they initialize the quantum register not the classical register.

Comment: Why dont u initialize qubits and measure them by the classical registers and finally reset the qubits.

Answer (score 0):

Here comes an illustration code written by myself.

```
from qiskit import QuantumRegister,ClassicalRegister,QuantumCircuit,Aer,execute
from qiskit.providers.aer import QasmSimulator
qr=QuantumRegister(1)
cr0=ClassicalRegister(5)
circ=QuantumCircuit(qr,cr0)
circ.measure(qr,cr0[0])
circ.x(qr)
circ.measure(qr,cr0[2])
circ.measure(qr,cr0[3])
circ.x(qr)
circ.measure(qr,cr0[3])
circ.x(qr)
circ.measure(qr,cr0[4])
circ.h(qr)
circ.x(qr)
print(execute(circ,Aer.get_backend('qasm_simulator')).result().get_counts())
```

[image: Quantum Circuit for the upper instruction]

The upper code shows how to get varied values and assign them to different classical registers. Although this method still requires a qubit, at least it can save some time. Maybe you can use the partial trace method to improve this. I think you must be ok with how the c_if() function works.

Comment: Haven't noticed that this is a rather old question, I hope this answer is now not that helpful for you.